# php switches my tinyint value

Tags: php, mysql, tinyint

Im new to php and with working with mysql.
I have table with users information:
[databse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwMue.png)

In login I get execute query, get all information:
[my php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDA4m.png)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'";
        //$result = mysql::query($query);
        $rows = mysql::select($query);
        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

        if(count($rows) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
            if($rows['admin'] == 1) {
                $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
            } else {
                $_SESSION['admin'] = false;
            }
            header("location: index.php");
        } else {
            $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
        }
```

and then I log user in, it logs in all perfectly, but then I try to read if I'm an admin, and my tinyint value always the opposite other than it's in database.

Maybe it is something that php does, and I should switch my if permanently, or it's my fault?

Comment: [Edit] your question to include your code as text.

Comment: Can you post the table definition and a sample of the data where this problem is happening

Comment: Don't store passwords in plain text - http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Little Bobby Tables approves of this question.

Comment: It would probably also be helpful to include the output of `var_dump($rows)` while you're adding info.

Comment: I'm curious where mysql::select comes from. My guess would be that you aren't receiving an associative array so $rows['admin'] would never exist.

Comment: mysql::connect is from mysql class I created, and I'm receiving data, because I can log on, only problem is my $_SESSION['admin'] is false then in databse my tinyint named 'admin' is 1 and vice verca

Comment: It looks like your `$_SESSION['login_user']` uses the value that was originally passed into the php script, and does not read the username back from the database result.  I'd still be very interested in seeing a `var_dump($rows);` from right before the `if(count...` part, but failing that, what happens if you change your username code to be `$_SESSION['login_user'] = $rows['username'];` ?  Does your username still get set properly?  How about if you do `$rows[0]['username']` ?